# What is resume= used for in my grub boot settings?

Tags: grub, sles

I've always noticed the `resume=/dev/foo` entry in /boot/grub/menu.lst, and that it corresponds to the swap partition, but I've never questioned its use.

```
title SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP2 - 3.0.13-0.27 (default)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.13-0.27-default root=/dev/sda1 insmod=qla4xxx resume=/dev/sda2 crashkernel=256M-:128M showopts
    initrd /boot/initrd-3.0.13-0.27-default
```

I was rebooting a server this morning and saw a boot message stating `Starting manual resume from disk`.  Sounds like some sort of hibernate.  So what exactly is resume?  I'm trying to Google it, but all I'm seeing is resumes/CVs for Linux Admins :).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [the list of kernel parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html):

```
resume=     [SWSUSP]
        Specify the partition device for software suspend
```

where

```
SWSUSP  Software suspend (hibernation) is enabled.
```

So yes, it's used for hibernation.

Comment: Thanks for the info and link.  Removing the `resume=` option and specifying the `noresume` option disables it.